# Join a variable number of ranges

Tags: c++, boost, range

I need to concatenate multiple instances of `boost::iterator_range`.
My initial idea was to use `boost::join`, but it looks like it takes only two ranges as parameters.
On another question I found that the most voted answer was "well, just call join again", but that is not working in my case.
I realized the reason might be that I do not know at compile time the exact number of ranges I am going to join, resulting in `boost::join` not knowing its return type.
To make it more clear, I need to use it in a ranged for loop, such as the following:

```
SomeRangeType result;

for ( const auto& a_range : some_list_of_ranges )
{
    result = boost::join( result, a_range );
}

return result;
```

Does another join-like operation like the one I need exist in `boost`?

Answer (score 5):

[range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) has `concat` and `join` views, it seems you want join view here:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1, 2, 3}, {4}, {5, 6}};

for (auto e : v | ranges::view::join) {
    std::cout << e << " "; // 1 2 3 4 5 6
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90d3b8376fe062fa)

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have run-time dynamic templates, so the idea does not work with `boost::range`.

We can have 2 ranges `r1` and `r2` with types `R1` and `R2` and when we `join` those then we get result (lets name it `r12`) of type `boost::joined_range<R1,R2>`.

We can have third range (say `r3` of type `R3`) and `join`ing it with `r12` we would get result of type `boost::joined_range<boost::joined_range<R1,R2>,R3>`.

The ranges `r1`, `r2`, `r3` etc. can be passed to variadic template function as arguments and from list of arguments we can make compiler to figure what is the resulting type. Same is when we have the ranges in fixed length collection (like `std::tuple` or `std::array`), we can make compiler to figure what is the resulting type of joining those.

However if we don't have fixed amount of ranges but run-time dynamic amount (like from `std::vector`) then we don't know what will be the type of joining these and also compiler can't figure it out compile time. Every type however must be known compile time in C++.

So you have either to find a way to fix the amount of ranges you join compile time or you have to use that dynamic, not joined collection (like `vector`) of ranges as your data type or you have to use some third thing like range-v3.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why `boost::join` does not work. But an `std::vector` of ranges would not be iterable the way I need it to be iterated... do you maybe have an idea on of how to solve that part?

Comment: You can write your own iterator that (by combining two iterators) iterates like you want to.

Comment: I hoped such an issue was already solved by a library like `boost`. As much as I like the efficiency of the compile-time version of boost::join, I am actually surprised (in a negative way) there is not a runtime version of it.

Comment: Then you have to use range-v3 that is not part of boost (or std) yet.