# Transforming a C++ nested loop into a single one with an iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, nested-loops

Let's say we have the following nested loop:

```
MyClass myobject;

for (const std::array<int,16>& arr : myobject)
{
    for (int i : arr)  {  /* do something with i */  }
}
```

where `MyClass` can iterate over arrays of 16 integers for instance.

Now, I would like to have a single loop that iterates over all integers of all arrays of `myobject`:

```
for (int i : MagicClass(myobject))  {  /* do something with i */  }
```

where `MagicClass` is the class I am trying to design. I understand that `MagicClass` should implement `begin/end` methods that return a specific iterator, ie. something like:

```
class MagicClass
{
public:
    MagicClass (MyClass obj) : obj_(obj) {}

    struct iterator 
    {
        // the hard part comes here...
    };

    iterator begin()  { return iterator (obj_.begin()); }
    iterator end  ()  { return iterator (obj_.end  ()); }

private:
    MyClass obj_;
};
```

Since I am struggling to get a decent implementation of `MagicClass::iterator`, I am wondering whether a generic solution already exists.

Is there any library that can transform a nested loop (a container iterating other containers) into a single loop through a single iterator ? Or at least, what should be the best practice to implement `MagicClass::iterator` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called [`std::views::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_view).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 3>,3> arr = {{
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9},
    }};

    for (int x : arr | std::views::join)
        std::cout << x << '\n'; // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
}
```

Comment: There's also `std::views::zip`. Zipping `arr` here would give 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9.

Comment: @TooZni It's not just transposing the arrays. It would give something like `{1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9}`, where each of the three groups is a `std::tuple`. This also means that the size of the outer array must be fixed at compile-time.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Shouldn't have just gone off memory :p

Comment: For the record, I found this related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496613/how-can-i-design-a-standalone-c17-stdviewsjoin-alternative; actually, I am in a similar context where I can't use ```std::views::join``` directly. Thanks anyway for your answer.